# canvas - How to center ontop

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a problem i have been battling for the last hour. Basically this code shows a clock, and an image of a deer. **I want the clock and the deer centered and the clock on top of the deer as in this image**:

But whatever I do I cant get it to work. Anyone got a solution for this ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<body bgcolor="#000000">

<style type="text/css">
.bgimg {
    background-image: url(klockren.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 
    height:800px;
}
#canvas {
       margin-left:85px;
    margin-top:420px;
}
</style>

<div align="center" class="bgimg">

   <div class="canvas">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
radius = radius * 0.90
setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

function drawClock() {
  drawFace(ctx, radius);
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
  drawTime(ctx, radius);
}

function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
  var grad;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,radius*0.95, 0,0,radius*1.05);
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'black');
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
  ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
  ctx.lineWidth = radius*0.1;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius*0.1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
  var ang;
  var num;
  ctx.font = radius*0.15 + "px arial";
  ctx.textBaseline="middle";
  ctx.textAlign="center";
  for(num = 1; num < 13; num++){
    ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }
}

function drawTime(ctx, radius){
    var now = new Date();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    var second = now.getSeconds();
    //hour
    hour=hour%12;
    hour=(hour*Math.PI/6)+
    (minute*Math.PI/(6*60))+
    (second*Math.PI/(360*60));
    drawHand(ctx, hour, radius*0.5, radius*0.07);
    //minute
    minute=(minute*Math.PI/30)+(second*Math.PI/(30*60));
    drawHand(ctx, minute, radius*0.8, radius*0.07);
    // second
    second=(second*Math.PI/30);
    drawHand(ctx, second, radius*0.9, radius*0.02);
}

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.rotate(pos);
    ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(-pos);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You also have two body tags (just in case it wasn't an accident pasting it in here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a css for this hope this helps

```
    <div align="center" class="bgimg">

<div align="center">

<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"

style="background-color:#fff">

</canvas>
</div>
</div>



    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
radius = radius * 0.90
setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

function drawClock() {
  drawFace(ctx, radius);
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
  drawTime(ctx, radius);
}

function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
  var grad;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,radius*0.95, 0,0,radius*1.05);
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
  ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
  ctx.lineWidth = radius*0.1;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius*0.1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
  var ang;
  var num;
  ctx.font = radius*0.15 + "px arial";
  ctx.textBaseline="middle";
  ctx.textAlign="center";
  for(num = 1; num < 13; num++){
    ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }
}

function drawTime(ctx, radius){
    var now = new Date();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    var second = now.getSeconds();
    //hour
    hour=hour%12;
    hour=(hour*Math.PI/6)+
    (minute*Math.PI/(6*60))+
    (second*Math.PI/(360*60));
    drawHand(ctx, hour, radius*0.5, radius*0.07);
    //minute
    minute=(minute*Math.PI/30)+(second*Math.PI/(30*60));
    drawHand(ctx, minute, radius*0.8, radius*0.07);
    // second
    second=(second*Math.PI/30);
    drawHand(ctx, second, radius*0.9, radius*0.02);
}

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.rotate(pos);
    ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(-pos);
}

.bgimg {
    background-image: url(http://klockren.se/klockren.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:570px;
}
#canvas {
       margin-left:370px;
    margin-top:240px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4heaex79/

Comment: Hi and thank you very much for this! the only problem i have now is when i try to resize my window everything goes of, i want the deer and the clock to stay onto of each other all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to align canvas properly:

```
 #canvas{
    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#clock {
    position: absolute;
    top: 270px;
    right: 340px;
}
```

Instead of background image, use image tag and then absolute position the clock.

See jsfiddle below.

https://jsfiddle.net/m3s7tvtc/

Answer (score 0):

The height of your deer image is 800 * 591 Pixels.

Set .bgimg to a relative position. Add class (.canvas) to the div around the canvas itself and set its position to absolute. Now set the top and left position until it fits into the middle where you want it.

Find an example below. You may want to edit it to suit your style.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
.bgimg {
    background-image: url(http://klockren.se/klockren.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:relative;
}
.canvas {position:absolute; top:250px; left:380px;}
</style>

<div align="center" class="bgimg">

   <div class="canvas">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
radius = radius * 0.90
setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

function drawClock() {
  drawFace(ctx, radius);
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
  drawTime(ctx, radius);
}

function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
  var grad;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,radius*0.95, 0,0,radius*1.05);
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
  ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
  ctx.lineWidth = radius*0.1;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius*0.1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
  var ang;
  var num;
  ctx.font = radius*0.15 + "px arial";
  ctx.textBaseline="middle";
  ctx.textAlign="center";
  for(num = 1; num < 13; num++){
    ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }
}

function drawTime(ctx, radius){
    var now = new Date();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    var second = now.getSeconds();
    //hour
    hour=hour%12;
    hour=(hour*Math.PI/6)+
    (minute*Math.PI/(6*60))+
    (second*Math.PI/(360*60));
    drawHand(ctx, hour, radius*0.5, radius*0.07);
    //minute
    minute=(minute*Math.PI/30)+(second*Math.PI/(30*60));
    drawHand(ctx, minute, radius*0.8, radius*0.07);
    // second
    second=(second*Math.PI/30);
    drawHand(ctx, second, radius*0.9, radius*0.02);
}

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.rotate(pos);
    ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(-pos);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: After I add `.bgimg { height:590px; }` this is the only answer that works for me.